# Using Future inside a View in play 2.3.2

Tags: html, scala, asynchronous, playframework

I'm writing a Play 2.3.2 application.
In my controller I've an asynchronous method that calculate a `Future[Option[(String, Int)]]`.

Because the calculation is slow I want to begin to create my view and when the computation is completed finish to construct the view.

In the same controller I've an action that call this method and load a view passing the results, like this:

```
def max = Action.async {
        calculateMax.flatMap(result => 
             Future{Ok(recommendationsystem.views.html.manager.statistics.max(result))

         )  

}
```

My max view is implemented like this:

```
@(max: scala.concurrent.Future[Option[(String, Int)]])

@import util._

@recommendationsystem.views.html.main("Max tag")(recommendationsystem.views.html.nav.navbar("statistics")) {
    <h1>Most used tag</h1>
    @max flatMap {result => result match {
    case Some(x) => {
        <p>
        <ul>
            <li>Tag: @x._1</li>
            <li>Occurrencies: @x._2</li>
        </ul>
        </p>


    }
    case None => {
        <p>No one tag present in the db</p>

    }
    }
    }

    <p><a href="@recommendationsystem.controllers.manager.routes.StatisticsController.index()"></a> </p>
}
```

But this code don't compile, the compiler gives me the following compile errors:

```
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/views/manager/statistics/max.scala.html:8: ')' expected but 'case' found.
[error]     case Some(x) => {
[error]     ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/views/manager/statistics/max.scala.html:18: ')' expected but 'case' found.
[error]     case None => {
[error]     ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/views/manager/statistics/max.scala.html:26: ';' expected but ',' found.
[error]     <p><a href="@recommendationsystem.controllers.manager.routes.StatisticsController.index()"></a> </p>
[error] ^
[error] three errors found
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/target/scala-2.11/twirl/main/recommendationsystem/views/html/manager/statistics/max.template.scala:27: ')' expected but 'case' found.
[error]     """),_display_(/*7.6*/max),format.raw/*7.9*/(""" """),format.raw/*7.10*/("""flatMap """),format.raw/*7.18*/("""{"""),format.raw/*7.19*/("""result => result match """),format.raw/*7.42*/("""{""")/*8.5*/case Some(x) =>/*8.20*/ {_display_(Seq[Any](format.raw/*8.22*/("""
[error]                                                                                                                                                                                                              ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/target/scala-2.11/twirl/main/recommendationsystem/views/html/manager/statistics/max.template.scala:36: ')' expected but 'case' found.
[error]     """)))}/*18.5*/case None =>/*18.17*/ {_display_(Seq[Any](format.raw/*18.19*/("""
[error]                    ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/target/scala-2.11/twirl/main/recommendationsystem/views/html/manager/statistics/max.template.scala:40: ';' expected but ',' found.
[error]     """)))},format.raw/*23.5*/("""}"""),format.raw/*23.6*/("""
[error]
```

Seems that the view cannot see the Future type.
What's wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compilation errors here are from your twirl syntax, and not the `Future`. Twirl templates are very picky with spacing and new lines. The `@max flatMap` with the space is definitely going to break some things, because twirl doesn't know if it should print out `max`, or look for more code. It may be best to surround the whole block with `@{ ... }`.

Some of this is irrelevant though, because you should never be passing a `Future` to a view in the first place. The template isn't going to partially render and then fill in the `Future` value later. Wrapping `recommendationsystem.views.html.manager.statistics.max` in `Future.apply` essentially does nothing. The key thing to note here is that `result` isn't even a `Future`. Presuming that `calculateMax` returns `Future[Option[(String, Int)]]`, when you call `map`, you're asynchronously operating on the `Option[(String, Int)]` result of that `Future`.

So your controller function should look like this:

```
def max = Action.async {
    calculateMax.map(result => 
        Ok(recommendationsystem.views.html.manager.statistics.max(result))
    )
}
```

And your view something like this:

```
@(max: Option[(String, Int)])

    @max match {
       case Some(x) => {
           ...
       }
       case None => {
           <p>No one tag present in the db</p>
       }
    }
```